# Make.com's Gmail node has an uncatchable error

Tags: make.com

Our integration uses [Gmail: Watch Emails](https://www.make.com/en/help/app/gmail#watch-emails-975546) node. And occasionally, it throws this error:

[image]

We have error handling in it. It even catches this Gmail error properly:

```
HANDLED ERROR
type    ModuleTimeoutError
message The operation timed out
```

But when the first one happens, it acts as if there is no error handling - then it sends me an error email like there's no tomorrow.

Although the error doesn't happen after the next try, its irritating that it has been happening more frequently (like 3 times a week).

Do you guys have any insights on how to go about this? I find no resources about this, except node-imap related stuff.